# why the permission of the stack in process address space of linux is executive?

Tags: linux, kernel

The linux kernel sets the permission of statck of process to be executive. As we know, the stack contains data instead instructions gernerally, So I wonder the reason why the kenel does this.
Especially, the buffer overflow attacks store the malicious code into the stack generally and execute it when it successfully exploit the system. if the permission of stack is not executive, the attack should be avoided, is this right?
So in my opinion, to set the stack's permission to be executive is harmful, what's the real purpose of linux doing this even it's running a risk of buffer overflow attacking ?

Comment: I think the buffer overflow attacking is just overriding the return address to the malicious codes start address. Not writing codes to stack.

Comment: I think your question can be: why the data segment of one process has the executive permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux kernel *does* support the `NX` bit on CPUs that have it. The support has been there since 2004.

Some *distributions* ship with kernels that don't enable the options required to use `NX` but that's more to do with the fact that setting those options (specifically, using PAE mode) will cause the OS to not boot on certain hardware.

That's why I tend to recompile my kernel rather than taking the default supplied in a distro. That way, I'm certain it's optimised for *my* hardware rather than just the general case.

Comment: If you use "pmap" command in the shell, you will find the stack's permission is "rwxp", this indicates that the stack can be excuted, that's why I am confused, I think the perssion should be "rwp" to avoid code running in stack, so why linux makes this decision ?

Comment: @Florian, it depends on the kernel entirely. For example, my `pmap -x $$` output has: `bf827000 84K rw--- [ stack ]` - no execute allowed. I suspect either your CPU doesn't support `NX` or your kernel hasn't got things set up for it.

Comment: If so, can I make a simple conclusion that your system can avoid buffer overflow attacking ?

Comment: I think the buffer overflow attacking is just overriding the return address to the malicious codes start address. Not writing codes to stack.

Comment: @Florian, buffer overflows can still occur since the stack is writable. However, one particular vactor of attack is removed because, even if you get code on to the stack with a buffer overflow (massaging a return address so that it "returns" to that code), it won't run. That's still an attack but it's more just getting your app to crash rather than execute arbitrary code.

Comment: On a recently compiled 3.8.2 kernel on x86-64, `pmap $$` shows that the stack is e.g. `132K rw---    [ stack ]` which is *not* executable.

Comment: @tian_yufeng, yes, but the key "jump" binary was still stored in stack gernerally.

Comment: @paxdiablo, sorry for that I didn't get your idea. Can you explain more about how to run rw-stack code ?

Comment: @Florian, you can't _run_ code on the stack if it's set no-execute. I'm saying you can use a buffer overflow to change the stack but the primary attack vector is to place both the code you want run and the modified return address on to the stack with a buffer overrun. Then, when some function returns, it does so to _your_ code. `NX` prevents this since you can still change the return address but you need a _different_ way to get your malicious code in, since it won't execute on the stack.

Comment: @paxdiablo,Back to our original question:In what reason the kernel make the stack to be executive in the past kernel version?

Comment: @Florian, that's answered in the second paragraph. Not all hardware will even _boot_ if you try and use NX. So the default kernels don't do that. Only those kernels that know they'll be running on NX-capable hardware can assume it's okay.

Answer (score -2):

Linux is a *nix. All *nix are based on early OSs written in assembler/machine code, where the concept of security was non-existent and also unnecessary. As more people started using computers, the OS evolved into something with contributions from tons of people around the world, and more importantly, computers gained more inputs from the outside world.

Machine code only exists as a way to change the machine's behavior without modifying the hardware, nothing more. People these days use C, whose purpose was to make porting assembly/machine code to other processor architectures easier.

The stack is just a means for implementing recursion.

There is simply no concept of security in machine code nor C. It's up to the user to choose his abstractions that map to machine code. C is not one of them. No amount of human beings and time will have or ever will validate a codebase sized reasonably enough to be useful (such as the Linux kernel + libc), as it requires validating arithmetic equations scattered across millions of lines of code, moreover which is changing all the time and so is the compiler, moreso that the language itself is not even well defined. A single arithmetic error anywhere in a C program is enough to compromise the entire address space of that program. No amount of SELinux, stack smashing protection, ASLR, App Armor, NX-bit, guard pages, etc will solve this.

Your question is like asking a barbaric primitive male why he doesn't do yoga.

If you disable execution of code on the stack (which most OSs support these days) there are still infinite other ways to own C code - for example, replacing the return address and words below it to setup a call to an arbitrary function with malicious parameters. Now someone will be like "oh that can be fixed, you just need a canary", but no, that doesn't fix the fact that the language being used is C, and is just distracting people from the real problem here, which is that if you want security you can't have C. PERIOD.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this.But you didn't make the original question clear.I wonder in what cases the kernel should execute the code int stack which causes the stack executive?

Comment: @Florian: It depends on the version of your kernel and linux distribution, it would be hard to enumerate them all. "what's the real purpose of linux doing this even it's running a risk of buffer overflow attacking ?" Executable isn't something you turn "on". It's something that's always existed until people devised ways to disable it.

Comment: I can't think of why this question is downvoted other than sheer ignorance or offended fanboys. If there is a reason state you reason. If not, all that can be assumed is fanboyism. I'd like to see someone explain why _any_ part of what I said is wrong.

Comment: You're being downvoted because your answer is largely composed of your (rather silly) opinions about C, and doesn't actually answer the question at all.

Comment: @duskwuff: What I say is backed by massive amounts of both theoretical and empirical evidence spanning decades. In theory, any undefined behaviour whatsoever in your C code is a vulnerability. In practice, it happens in every commonly used code base [OSVDB]. More importantly, it's simply obvious to any novice that C cannot be used to create secure systems. Remember how you messed up and didn't get 100% in math class? Well, probably then your C code has vulns in it too. Fortunately it's trivial to implement a PL that doesn't have this problem. for example, lisp, which has been around forever.

Comment: @duskwuff: The question is implying there's any reason to disable executable stack. But there is not. It's only a workaround to make it harder to exploit bugs in a fundamentally insecure system. Only fix is to A) Write perfect C code. B) Write in a language that isn't so hard.